# list filtering with qcombobox and qlineedit

Tags: pyqt4, filtering, qlistwidget, qcombobox

I have a question on how to filter items from a ListWidget via combobox selection

Example, in my ListWidget, there are Yellow 01, Yellow 02, Blue 01, Red 01, Red 02 and Red 03
Whereas in my combobox, there are Yellow, Blue and Red

I guess, you got the gist of it, where if user selects the option Red in the combobox, the ListWidget will displays Red 01, Red 02, Red 03... And the same goes for the other 2 options.

Can someone guide me in this matter?

By the way, out of curiosity, can it be done if I were to integrate another text field (QLineEdit), 3 items in total and have it work the same functions as the combobox as well?

P.S: My Information is reading from a directory and hence it is a little tricky, i guess

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python.
Can you use a map with string as key and list of strings as values? Then, you can use the selected string and show the appropriate values ...

Comment: Hi walle, I don't really get what you mean... I am pretty new to the language python as well. Erm, could you kindly elaborate more on it?

Comment: In python its called [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping). The key is `QString`, and value is `QVector<QString>`. Then you can take the combobox string as key and get the listwidget entrys from the appropriate value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you created a ui file `myDialog.ui` with designer. The QListWidget and QComboBox are called `comboBox` and `listWidget`.
To update your QListWidget, I propose this approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 *-

import sys
import os

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
  def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"myDialog.ui"), self)
    self.comboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateList)
    self.comboBox.clear()
    self.comboBox.insertItems(0,self.getFilters())
    self.updateList()
    pass

  def updateList(self):
    items = self.getListItems()
    text_filter = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
    self.listWidget.clear()
    # If "All" is used, no filter is applied
    self.listWidget.insertItems(0,[text for text in items if text_filter in text + "All"])
    pass

  def getFilters(self):
    # Write here your own method to retrieve the filters
    return ["Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "All"]

  def getListItems(self):
    # Write here your own method to retrieve the list values
    return ["Yellow 01", "Yellow 02", "Blue 01", "Red 01", "Red 02", "Red 03 "]

myDialog = MyDialog()
myDialog.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi Frodon, thanks for getting back to me. I have a question in which I presumed your coding means that I have to do manual input right? Such as I will need to define that when Yellow is selected in the combobox, I have to type out all the words that contain Yellow under the updateList?

Am I right?

Comment: The filtering operation is already done in my example. You just have to rewrite the getFilters and getListItems methods to fill the comboBox and the listWidget with your own data. For instance the values for the listWidget can be a directory content (directories and files). It's up to you to write this part.